# Issue of alignment of string in textarea in Flex 3.0

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

I need to display a long string in a `TextArea` in the form of two columns. Say 20 characters of the string in left side and then some space and then 20 character on right side of `TextArea`. At next line again I am doing same thing till my string is complete.

But what is happening is like at right column all rows are not aligned exactly. This is happening because each character has different pixel width so alignment of right column depends on character printed on left column. if on left column characters are like 'iiii' then second column row starts a bit early in `TextArea` and if on left column, characters are like 'MMMMMM' then second column row starts a bit late.

I am using `<textFormat>` tag for text formatting into this string.

Comment: If anybody viewed this issue.Please respond me as this issue is now critical for me.

Comment: It would help if you showed some code.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the fontFamily of TextArea to Courier New.

fontFamily="Courier New"